# OpenCV: Cannot Use FaceTime

Tags: python, opencv, orb

I'm trying to use opencv in my mac with python for matching objects .

But I'm getting this error.

```
OpenCV: Cannot Use FaceTime HD Kamera (Yerleşik)
OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize!
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Also this is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

ESC=27   
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()


while True:

    ret, imgCamColor = camera.read()
    imgCamGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgCamColor, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kpCam = orb.detect(imgCamGray,None)
    kpCam, desCam = orb.compute(imgCamGray, kpCam)
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(desCam,desTrain)
    good = []


    cv2.imshow('Camara', result)

    key = cv2.waitKey(20)                                 
    if key == ESC:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
camera.release()
```

I tried a few things too.
 But its not worked.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Seeing the same thing on my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem with my OpenCV script. I recommend testing the camera via a built in app (Ex. Photo Booth). As you see with the image, the camera wasn't being detected. The solution was pretty simple, I **restarted my computer** or run the following command: `sudo killall VDCAssistant`.

[image]

My script used for testing the OpenCV **after** restarting my computer:

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

rval, frame = vc.read()

while True:

  if frame is not None:
     cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
  rval, frame = vc.read()

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break
```

Answer (score 6):

**Kill VDCAssistant process!**

Open *Activity Monitor* and kill VDCAssistant

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you're using macOS, I resolved this issue by granting permission for terminal to access camera in "Security and Privacy" section on System Preferences. Hope this solves issue [click here to view steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRWeH.png).

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved this issue. you should give permission to use the camera to iTerm or terminal

1. go to security and privacy in system preferences on mac osx
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhGeF.png)
2. give permission to iTerm to access the camera
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SBuO.png)